# If A Not Equal to B in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I understand IIF very well but I am trying to write an expression like the below in SSRS.

```
    IF A<>B,"D"
    =IIF(A <> B,"C","D") -- this doesn't work for me
```

What replaces the sign, "<>" in the expression?

Comment: `<>` is the "not equal" comparison operator in VB (the language of SSRS expressions)

Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do that isn't working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<>` may not work if your values contain `NULL` so you may have to run a multiple case comparison such as:

```
IiF(A<>B OR A IsNothing OR B IsNothing, "C", "D")
```

Comment: This isn't true in the VB.NET world. `Nothing` gets converted to whatever type it's being compared to, so `Nothing = ""` would evaluate to `True` as would `Nothing = Nothing`.

Comment: And I agree with you completely, but SSRS sometimes plays by its own rules (this assessment based on experience and not documented instances).

Answer (score 3):

This Code will work for you :

```
=IIF(Not A = B,"D","C")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using IIF, your true part should come first. I would switch the position of your C and D, because currently, if A<>B then it will show C, not D. Try this:

```
=IIF(A <> B,"D","C")
```